# Update the SQL column based on filter of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am stuck in a SQL query. I want to update the column STATUS using sql query.
The exact requirement is I have a SQL table as follows.

```
_____________________________________________
start_date          end_date        status
---------------------------------------------
2014/01/03      |   2018/01/03  |   FAILED
2016/12/15      |   2017/01/03  |   SUCCESS
2014/01/03      |   2010/01/13  |   FAILED
2017/10/23      |   2017/01/03  |   FAILED
2014/01/03      |   2011/01/03  |   FAILED
2017/11/13      |   2017/01/03  |   SUCCESS
---------------------------------------------
```

In the above table, I have start_date, end_date and status.
Now I want to update the status from "FAILED" to "SUSPEND" where the end_date is the oldest one among all the dates and start_date is same but end_date is different. (Here only one row will be updated as showing in the below table)

I am trying to build a query but unable to fetch the required result.
after applying a correct query, the table should look like as follows.

---

```
start_date          end_date        status
---------------------------------------------
2014/01/03      |   2018/01/03  |   FAILED
2016/12/15      |   2017/01/03  |   SUCCESS
2014/01/03      |   2010/01/13  |   SUSPEND
2017/10/23      |   2017/01/03  |   FAILED
2014/01/03      |   2011/01/03  |   FAILED
2017/11/13      |   2017/01/03  |   SUCCESS
---------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone please help me in this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there any PK in this table ? This looks like a bad design. What is the purpose of this table ?

Comment: "the end_date is the oldest one and start_date is same but end_date is different." what's the meaning of this sentence? start_date > end_date?

Comment: No there is no PK in the table. this is a sample table actual table has the huge amount of data and many columns.

Comment: @ZhongWang it means there are multiple end date but I want to update only that STATUS where end date is oldest among all dates.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: @JayeshVyas what is the datatype for your start_date and end_date columns. It seems they are not `date` type, instead `varchar`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya  I am using date as datatype for both dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), get minimum value of `end_date` for a group of `start_date`.
- Join it your main table based on `start_date` and `min_end_date`.
- Update `status` accordingly.

Try the following in MySQL (**[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/49HcLND86DEVYvHsggi96E/0)**):

```
UPDATE your_table AS t1
JOIN (SELECT start_date, 
             MIN(end_date) AS min_end_date 
      FROM your_table 
      GROUP BY start_date) AS t2 ON t2.start_date = t1.start_date AND 
                                    t2.min_end_date = t1.end_date 
SET t1.status = 'SUSPEND' 
WHERE t1.status = 'FAILED'
```

Comment: hey madhur it is giving error.                                                                                     Error at Command Line:52 Column:15
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"

Comment: @JayeshVyas are you using MySQL or Oracle Database (PL/SQL) ? It looks like you are definitely not using MySQL

Comment: I am using Sqldeveloper not PL/SQL

Comment: @JayeshVyas why did you tag this question as MySQL  ? My Solution works for MySQL. Oracle , MySQL, SQL Server etc are all different RDBMS and have different syntax at times. Anyways, I am editing answer to add solution for Oracle also.

Comment: @JayeshVyas please join me in chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181674/room-for-madhur-bhaiya-and-jayesh-vyas

Answer (score 0):

You could use an update using a where clause. I didn't understand what you mean with and start_date is same but end_date is different, so i didn use it.

```
UPDATE table1
SET status='SUSPEND'
WHERE status='FAILED' and end_date<start_date
```

Comment: thanks for ur quick response but I want to update only that particular row where status is FAILED and end date is the oldest one (plus I have to identified that how many rows has the same start dates.)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the logic Madhur told is correct except a functional bug. Since you were asking for oldest.. We should query using MIN instead of MAX as below

```
UPDATE your_table AS t1
JOIN (SELECT start_date, 
             MIN(end_date) AS max_end_date 
     FROM your_table 
     GROUP BY start_date) AS t2 ON t2.start_date = t1.start_date AND 
                                    t2.max_end_date = t1.end_date  
SET t1.status = 'SUSPEND' 
WHERE t1.status = 'FAILED'
```